# Flexbox prevent to show two elements side by side

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, flexbox

On large screens i want all elements on 1 row, on smaller i want three rows. Basically i dont want see button only with H1 on same row. How can flexbox solve this issue? thank you :)

```
<div class="buttoncontainer">
      <button class="change">Change background</button>
      <h1 id="currentcolor">currentcolor</h1>
      <button class="change">Change background</button>
    </div>
```

And css:

'''

```
.buttoncontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 90vh;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
button {
  border: 10px solid black;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-shadow: #222;
  box-shadow: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4.5;
  height: 25%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 20px;

}
h1 {
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
```

SO i dont want this :[Bad one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoEcc.png)

But straight to this[GOod one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWxdE.png)

Comment: If your changing things due to screen size, use mediaqueries. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to solve this problem would be through Media Queries. Media queries make it so you can easily set a max or min width for things to happen a certain way.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

From what I'm understanding, you can set it so whenever it's less than a certain resolution (in this case I set 900px), the flex-direction property should be set to 'column'.

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .buttoncontainer {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
```

This should solve your problem.